Docusign settings through master resource file not working to remove Certificate
I am trying to disable the 'View Certificate (PDF)' action in the toggle bar during signing for a recipient. I'm trying to do it through the master resource file, as I didn't see this options in the settings interface.
View Certificate Button in toggle
I've attempted to change the View Certificate to 'Hidden' but this only amends the data label name. The reference in the Master resource file is:
<root>
<language twoletterisoname="">
    <data name="DocuSign_Certificate">View Certificate</data>
</language>
</root>

Would anyone be familiar enough with this to provide the xml to remove this?
Thanks!

This settings cannot be directly controlled by the user.
You can still remove this option for recipients during signing. However, you cannot do it yourself.
You need to contact Docusign Customer Support and they'll do this for you.
